# Chirpy does not create code behind files?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, code-behind, chirpy

Apparently I installed the Chripy Add-In for Visual Studio 2010, it does appear in the Add-In manager, I did configure the Coffee-Script path to my local coffee.exe file,
but still nothing shows up in Visual Studio, when I add a .coffee file to the MVC3 project (in the script folder).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just downloaded the current version of Chirpy from Codeplex (ver 2.01) and experienced the same issue. Using this guide from [Weirdlover](http://www.weirdlover.com/2011/03/03/chirpy-v2/), you will note that in [step 2](http://www.weirdlover.com/2011/03/03/chirpy-v2/#coffeescript) he suggests that one adds a `.chirpy.coffee` file. The problem is that the add-in is pre-configure to look for `.chirp.coffee` (Tools -> Options -> Chirpy ->CoffeeScript), notice the lack of a 'y'. You can either change the Chirpy options or rename your file.